# Is any method to connect to iphone by bluetooth without asking accept?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is any method to connect to iphone by bluetooth without asking accept?

I want to write program with witch user can connect to each other without asking acception to connect to this program?

Is any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO.

And to fulfill the 30 character limit: is it possible on any device? can you imagine the consequences if this is possible?

Comment: Is any method to set filter for connections to only who has same program? This is like LAN game.

Comment: explore game kit. it is made for multiplayer games etc... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html